# How to use nextjs with multiple plugins

Tags: reactjs, antd, next.js

I'm using Nextjs with a [with-antd](https://github.com/hanpama/next-with-antd) boilerplate and it comes with a preconfigured `next.config.js` file.

Looking like this;

```js
/* eslint-disable */
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')

// fix: prevents error when .css files are required by node
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.css'] = (file) => {}
}

module.exports = withCss()
```

I want to edit this configuration file and add configurations like `exportPathMap`.

Like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: function () {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/about': { page: '/about' },
      '/p/hello-nextjs': { page: '/post', query: { title: 'Hello Next.js' } },
      '/p/learn-nextjs': { page: '/post', query: { title: 'Learn Next.js is awesome' } },
      '/p/deploy-nextjs': { page: '/post', query: { title: 'Deploy apps with Zeit' } }
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement that without breaking the `withCss` plugin, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by realizing that next-plugins *such as `@zeit/next-css` that I was using* expect more next configurations that are passed as objects from the plugin.

Snippet from `@zeit/next-css` plugin.

```js
module.exports = (nextConfig = {}) => {
  return Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
    webpack(config, options) {
      if (!options.defaultLoaders) {
        throw new Error(
          'This plugin is not compatible with Next.js versions below 5.0.0 https://err.sh/next-plugins/upgrade'
        )
}
```

So with that figured out I fixed the `exportPathMap` as an object inside `withCss`.

```js
module.exports = withCss({
    exportPathMap: function() {
        return {
            '/': {page: '/'},
            '/sevices': {page: '/services'},
            '/about': {page: '/about'},
            '/contacts': {page: '/contacts'},
        }
    }
})
```

That's it!